# Microsoft.ML holding on to data

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm writing a test case which generates images, I then have the Microsoft.ML prediction engine classify these images, and at the end of the test I want to delete the images I created. The problem is that when I try to delete them I get an error "The process cannot access the file "C:..." because it is being used by another process.

Is there any way to remove my image file from the process? or to dispose of the PredictionEngine holding on to the image?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/4585) on github dotnet/machinelearning project. I hope they give us a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed with this issue https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/4585.
I think that It will be included in the next release of the nuget package.

**UPDATE**

I confirm that this bug was fixed with release 1.5.0 (https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/releases/tag/v1.5.0)